# Ionic / Angular.js- Converting Binary Image Data to Image

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-s3, ionic-framework, laravel-5.1

In my Ionic App, I have a Laravel webservice that is pulling an image file from AWS S3.  The S3 bcuket is secured with an IAM user.  Therefore just by simply pointing to the http://S3URL/bucket/imagename.jpg would not work.  Instead my API returns a binary stream.  I tried converting the binary stream into an image that can be displayed by using the following:

```
 $scope.receiptdata = response.data; // (response from My web service)
 var basestring = "data:image/png;base64,";
 $scope.newreceipt = basestring + $scope.receiptdata;
```

And then in my view

However, I received a blank view.   I have tested the view with another static image by pointing to a remote url and I know for a fact that it works.   Is there a way to display the the image.  I am trying not to do away with all the security in my S3 bucket as the images are specific to the users and I don't want other than the user who owns it to own it.

Comment: So basically the proble with your conversion, near converting the binary stream into an image right ?

Comment: that is correct @Jigar7521

Comment: are you using ajax for to retrieve data of image?

Comment: @Jigar7521- no It is an ionic / angularjs script.  I am using http.get to make a rest call to my API server which calls S3 to fetch the file.   $file = Storage::disk('s3')->get('filename');

Comment: Ok so i think before to get response from your API call, it is not waiting till, and continuing execution ahead, that's why it happening

Comment: @Jigar7521 - No actually it completes the call.  Because I print the entire steam in the console.log  Also the img ng-src tag is called in a modal.  Modal view works for a static image url.